# How pass data to an UICollectionView embedded in a TableViewCell (xCode - iOS - Swift 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I implemented a CollectionView in a TableViewCell but I need read dynamic data for set cells on CollectionView.

I can read data on extension from class TableViewCell, maybe can help me pass data from ViewController to the class TableViewCell.

```
 class MultipleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    }

    extension MultipleTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 3 // array.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCollectionViewCell

     let dict = array.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary //Like this

            cell.name.text = "How do you read data from ViewController"
            cell.email.text = "How do you read data from ViewController"
            cell.phone.text =  dict["phone"] as? String //Like this
            cell.image.image = "How do you read data from ViewController"

            return cell
        }

    }

    extension MultipleFoodTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 1
            let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 20
            let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
            let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        }

    }
```

Comment: In cell for row at index path in your view controller, could you not just say cell.collectionView.dataSource = self?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is create one method inside your `MultipleTableViewCell` with datasource array that you want to fill with `CollectionView`. Now call this method in `cellForRowAt` method of `TableView`.

```
class MultipleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

     var array = [String]() //Change with Your array type

     func fillCollectionView(with array: [String]) {
          self.array = array
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Now call this method in `cellForRowAt` and pass the datasource array for `collectionView`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier") as! MultipleTableViewCell
    cell.fillCollectionView(with: ["A","B","C"]) //Pass your array
    return cell
}
```