# Assign an array From UIViewController to a Custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Im working on a project in swift 3 and it contains a UICollectionview inside a UItableViewCell. Therefore I have three Class in the order of UIViewController,UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewCell. The codes of the the classes as bellow.

UIViewController

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 160
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return (section%2 == 0) ? "Games":"Love"
    }
```

UITableViewCell

```
extension TableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageNames.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell



    cell.naeLabel.text = imageNames [indexPath.row]


    return cell

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let clickedIndex = imageNames[indexPath.row]

    print(clickedIndex)


}

}
```

My requirement is to pass an array from UIViewController to UITableViewCell. How could I achieve this?

Comment: May be this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651196/how-pass-data-to-an-uicollectionview-embedded-in-a-tableviewcell-xcode-ios

Comment: From cellForRow method it will let u access "var array" but not the method "fillCollectionView". Any idea why ?

Comment: Same thing is working for me, where you have added this function fillCollectionView?

Comment: In the UITableViewCell class before " func awakeFromNib() "... Basically I can print the array which i have in my UIViewController class. But once i pass it to the UItableViewCell class, it shows an empty array. Sir why is that

Comment: Edit your question with your current code that you are trying.

Comment: Welcome mate :)