# iOS Tableviewcell contain CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image: Expectation outcome]

Recently, I have trying to putting collection view cell into table view cell in a certain row.
I manage to do like this

[image: Currently outcome]

But somehow I cannot further design it.
When I calling

```
cell.productName.text = "text"
```

This is my tableviewcell code

```
class RProductCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

    self.bounds = CGRect(x: 90, y: 90, width: screenWidth, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(CollectionProductCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "productcollection")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    
    self.addSubview(collectionView)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productcollection", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionProductCell
    if indexPath.row%2 == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
    
    return cell
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

and this is mine collectionviewcell code

```
class CollectionProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

}
```

and this is my collection view design

Hope I explain clearly to solve my problem. Or giving new suggestion to help me do this in another way.

Thanks

Comment: You can try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42654038/6433023

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your expected output, i think you should use horizontal  stack-view rather than collection view.It comes with uiview which can be customize according to your expectation.

Comment: Sorry, i never use horizontal stack-view before. can you explain more about it?

Comment: you can look here at https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: no it cant,you have to take scroll view add stack-view having sub views of nsviews on it. and you can customize those views as you want.for refence check Menucar for uber in Mac App Store .